# Background color height

Tags: html, css

I am building a website and have come across an issue. The background color does not reach the position I would like it to be. It is only across half the screen instead of the full page. I need it to be a bit higher. I am not sure how to do this.

It is only across half the screen. How do I fix this? If you need more information, feel free to ask.

[image]

```css
#aboit {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

#aboit .block3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 225px;
  height: 225px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 320px;
  background-color: #FFE8F2;
}

#aboit .block4 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 225px;
  height: 225px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 320px;
  background-color: #FFE8F2;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

#aboit .toixte {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 660px;
  right: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#aboit .toitle {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 660px;
  right: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="aboit">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block3"></div>
    <div class="block3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="block4"></div>
    <div class="block4"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="toitle">
      <p><b>About Us</b>
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="toixte">
      <p>We provide only the best cakes to our <br>customers. Each cake is made with love <br>and care, ensuring that our customers are <br>always taken care of. Our cakes are <br>available for pickup or, delivery applies if <br>you are in a certain area</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </p>
  </p>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve]

Comment: You seem to have a few extra closing tags in your html. Maybe this is causing your issue?

Comment: You should delete `</p>
</p>
</div>
</div>` At the end

Comment: unfortunately, this does not resolve it @Fakt309

Comment: Actually, i don't understand. On my screen full page is grey.

Comment: If you need half height. Use `height: 50vh` If you need full window height, you can use `100vh`

Comment: In my chrome, all that position:relative makes the page start halfway down the page with the top half off screen. Can you make the snippet look like your drawing when run?

Comment: @mplungjan agree with you. I have the same

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .about {
      background: lightgray;
      height: 100vh;

  }
  .all {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .about-description {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 150px;
  }
  .blocks {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
      margin-top: 50px;
  }
  .block {
      background-color: #ffe4f1;
      width: 225px;
      height: 225px;
      margin: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="all">
                <div class="about-description">
                    <h2>About Us</h2>
                    <p align="center">We provide only the best cakes to our <br>customers. Each cake is made with love <br>and care, ensuring that our customers are <br>always taken care of. Our cakes are <br>available for pickup or, delivery applies if <br>you are in a certain area</p>
                </div>
                <div class="blocks">
                    <div class="block"></div>
                    <div class="block"></div>
                    <div class="block"></div>
                    <div class="block"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I only see half a page in Chrome

Comment: @mplungjan it is the same in the question asked when you run it i only fixed the background problem which was asked in the question

Comment: But that is only half a solution

Comment: @mplungjan i am doing it all again from start it is about to be finished wait

Answer (score 0):

remove `background-color: lightgrey;` from `#aboit` and style in this way:

```css
#aboit {
position:relative;
}

#aboit::before{
content: '';
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 60% // you can change to fit 
background-color: lightgrey;
}
```